# How safe is travel to Venezuela right now?

Tags: safety, airport-security, security, venezuela

How safe is travel to Venezuela right now (Nov/Dec 2016)? By that I mean TO Venezuela, not IN Venezuela.

In my case I would be traveling to a large hotel in Caracas to do cash business and can pay for an armed escort to the hotel if necessary. My main concern is not so much street gangs, as the possibility that state soldiers or gendarmes (or whatever they call them) would try to rob me or shake me down in the airport.

Concerning getting to the hotel, do I need an armed escort and if so, how large does that escort need to be? 3 men, 5 men, 10 men, 20 men? How many would be advisable?

Comment: No clue what the answer is, but curious to know if we're talking cartel here.

Comment: @GayotFow I am a book dealer. I buy books and maps.

Comment: @pnuts I find it kind of unbelievable the idea that a security company that I would hire would rob me. Such a security company would not be in business long. If I hire a security company, it will be one that has a good reputation and references, which it will not have if it is robbing its own clients.

Comment: I think you have seen too much movies :) Venezuela is not more dangerous that its neighbour countries right now or in the past. Just use common sense and look lika a tourist (because it's impossible to look like a local).

Comment: Never been to Venezuela. All I know is that I have heard rumors of the police robbing people in airports and I want to verify if that is a legitimate concern and how to avoid that happening to me.

Answer (score 4):

https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/venezuela

Pay attention for this part of security advisory:)

"Authorities (e.g. police, airport, immigration) and criminals posing as authorities have harassed and extorted money from tourists"